# Dynamic allocation of a 2D matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I'm a beginner with C and I'm trying to learn how to work with dynamic allocation of 2D matrixes. Can someone tell me why it gives me problems? (In the `main` function, I used 10 and 11 as test sizes.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void insert_values(int **arr, int dim, int size);

void resize(int ***arr, int dim) {
    if (*arr == NULL) { 
        *arr = (int **)malloc(dim * sizeof(int *));
        if (!*arr) return; 
    } 
    else { 
        *arr = (int **)realloc(*arr, dim * sizeof(int *));
        if (*arr == NULL) return; 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) { 
        if ((*arr)[i] == NULL) { 
            (*arr)[i] = (int *)malloc(dim * sizeof(int));

            if (!(*arr)[i]) return; 

            break;
        }
        else { //se esiste la posizione allora lo rialloco
            (*arr)[i] = (int *)realloc(**arr, dim * sizeof(int));
 
            if ((*arr)[i] == NULL) return;
        }
    }
}
    
void insert_values(int **arr, int dim, int size) {
    if (size > dim) {
        resize(&(arr), size);
    }

    int x;
    int y;

    for(x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            arr[x][y] = x + y;
            printf("%d |", arr[x][y]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}

void print_values(int **arr, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            printf("%d |", *(arr+i)[j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int **x =  (int**)malloc(10 * sizeof(*x));

    if (!x) { return 0; }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        x[i] = (int*)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    }

    insert_values(x, 10, 11);
    print_values(x, 11);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        free(x[i]);
    }

    free(x);
}
```

```
0 |1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |6 |7 |8 |9 |10 |
1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |6 |7 |8 |9 |10 |11 |
2 |3 |4 |5 |6 |7 |8 |9 |10 |11 |12 |
3 |4 |5 |6 |7 |8 |9 |10 |11 |12 |13 |
4 |5 |6 |7 |8 |9 |10 |11 |12 |13 |14 |
5 |6 |7 |8 |9 |10 |11 |12 |13 |14 |15 |
6 |7 |8 |9 |10 |11 |12 |13 |14 |15 |16 |
7 |8 |9 |10 |11 |12 |13 |14 |15 |16 |17 |
8 |9 |10 |11 |12 |13 |14 |15 |16 |17 |18 |
9 |10 |11 |12 |13 |14 |15 |16 |17 |18 |19 |
10 |11 |12 |13 |14 |15 |16 |17 |18 |19 |20 |
-533986992 |-533955728 |
```

This is the output that during `insert_values` works but in `print_values` it gives me a segmentation fault.

Comment: This is very odd. `*(arr+i)[j]` vs. just `arr[i][j]`

Comment: Beware the [Three-Star Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) epithet.  They may be unavoidable, but you should avoid triple stars when you can.  Consider creating a matrix structure.  However, that's tangential to your problem.

Comment: See also [**Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: Note that it is allowed to `realloc` a null pointer, so in `resize()`, you do not need the `if (*arr == NULL) {` part and can just do `*arr = (int **)realloc(*arr, dim * sizeof(int *));` regardless of whether `*arr` is `NULL` or not.

Comment: The `resize()` function really needs to know both the old size and the new size, because when `realloc()` returns a larger block than the original, the extra space contains junk. The code needs to initialize the extra space without damaging the original space.

Comment: Note that the pattern `oldptr = realloc(oldptr, newsize);` is an antipattern.  If the reallocation fails, you've leaked the old memory.  You should always use: `void *newptr = realloc(oldptr, newsize); if (newptr == NULL) { …handle failure… } oldptr = newptr; /* oldsize = newsize; */`.  In the 'handle failure' code, `oldptr` still points to the original data, which could be freed or otherwise used safely.  You probably shouldn't change the `oldsize` until after the reallocation succeeds, as shown in the correct fragment.

Comment: Don't take pointers by reference. Instead, take them by value and return a new value. Does `realloc` take a pointer by reference? No. Your `resize` is a slightly souped up `realloc`, so why should it have a radically different interface?

Comment: Not only will it free you from the three star syndrome, but it will also help you avoid mistakes like you currently have with insert_values. (Don't see the mistake? Answer then, if insert_values can resize, why does it take a two star argument and resize needs a three star one?

Answer (score 1):

**`resize()` thoughts**

Other code may need work too.

- `void resize()` needs to know both the new and old dimensions. [@Ian Abbott](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77181144/dynamic-allocation-of-a-2d-matrix-in-c/77181637#comment136063666_77181144)
- A general `resize()` would work with an increasing and decreasing re-sizing.
- The result of `*alloc()` does not need a cast.  Remove to reduce clutter.
- Within `resize()`, consider dereferencing the address of the passed in pointer for clearer code.
- Tolerate dimensions with size 0.
- Sizing to the de-reference pointer is less error prone, easier to review and maintain than sizing to the type.

---

Here is an untested candidate `resize()` re-write to illustrate these ideas.
Simplified out-of-memory handling.  Adjust as desired.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void resize(int ***arr, size_t old_rows, size_t old_columns, size_t new_rows,
    size_t new_columns) {
  // For clearer code, de-reference the pointer into a local variable.
  int **arr2 = *arr;

  // If shrinking rows, free excess rows.
  if (new_rows < old_rows) { 
    for (size_t r = new_rows; r < old_rows; r++) {
      free(arr2[r]);
    }
    old_rows = new_rows;
  }
  // Reallocate rows
  arr2 = realloc(arr2, sizeof arr2[0] * new_rows);
  if (arr2 == NULL && new_rows > 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Allocation failure\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // Reallocate old row for the new column width.
  for (size_t r = 0; r < old_rows; r++) {
    arr2[r] = realloc(arr2[r], sizeof arr2[r][0] * new_columns);
    if (arr2[r] == NULL && new_columns > 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Allocation failure\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // Zero new columns
    for (size_t c = old_columns; c < new_columns; c++) {
      arr2[r][c] = 0;
    }
  }
  // Assign new rows
  for (size_t r = old_rows; r < new_rows; r++) {
    arr2[r] = calloc(new_columns, sizeof arr2[r][0]);
    if (arr2[r] == NULL && new_columns > 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Allocation failure\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }

  *arr = arr2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issues with your code have been identified, and it has been suggested that you create an actual `Matrix` type to represent your matrix, rather than having to pass around triple pointers. It may help you to see how this approach would affect your code.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { 
    size_t dim;
    int **data;
} Matrix;

typedef int (*matrix_cell_initializer_func)(size_t row, size_t col);

// Interface for working with matrices
Matrix *new_matrix(size_t dim);
void free_matrix(Matrix *m);
void init_matrix(Matrix *m, matrix_cell_initializer_func f);
void print_matrix(Matrix *m);
Matrix *resize_matrix(Matrix *m, size_t new_dim);

int init(size_t row, size_t col);

int main(void) {
    Matrix *m = new_matrix(5);

    resize_matrix(m, 6);
    init_matrix(m, init);
    print_matrix(m);
    free_matrix(m);
    free(m);
}

// Implementations of matrix functions.

Matrix *new_matrix(size_t dim) {
    Matrix *m = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
    if (!m) return NULL;

    m->data = malloc(sizeof(int *) * dim);
    if (!m->data) {
        free(m);
        return NULL;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        m->data[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * dim);
        if (!(m->data[i])) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                free(m->data[j]);
            }

            free(m);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    m->dim = dim;

    return m;
}

void free_matrix(Matrix *m) {
    if (!m) return;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m->dim; i++) {
        if (m->data[i]) free(m->data[i]);
    } 
}

void init_matrix(Matrix *m, matrix_cell_initializer_func f) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m->dim; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < m->dim; j++) {
            m->data[i][j] = f(i, j);
        }
    }
}

void print_matrix(Matrix *m) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m->dim; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < m->dim; j++) {
            printf(" %8d ", m->data[i][j]);
        }

        puts("\n");
    }
}

int init(size_t row, size_t col) {
    return row * col + row; 
}

Matrix *resize_matrix(Matrix *m, size_t new_dim) {
    if (new_dim < m->dim) return NULL;
    if (new_dim == m->dim) return m;

    int **new_data = realloc(m->data, sizeof(int *) * new_dim);
    if (!new_data) return NULL;

    m->data = new_data;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < new_dim; i++) {
        int *new_row = realloc(m->data[i], sizeof(int) * new_dim);
        if (!new_row) return NULL;

        m->data[i] = new_row;
    }

    m->dim = new_dim;

    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code.

Made the following changes to make it work:

1. redefined the resize function to take original size as an input
   This will help initialize the additional array pointers due to resizing to NULL.
   Added to code initialize this additional allocated pointers to NULL in this function
2. From function insert_values called resize function with the additional parameter (original size)
3. replaced the *(arr + i)[j] in printf statement in print_values function to arr[i][j]

> Blockquote

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void insert_values(int** arr, int dim, int size);

void resize(int*** arr, int dim, int original_size) {
    if (*arr == NULL) {
        *arr = (int**)malloc(dim * sizeof(int*));
        if (!*arr) return;
    }
    else {
        *arr = (int**)realloc(*arr, dim * sizeof(int*));
        if (*arr == NULL) return;

        for (int i = original_size; i < dim; i++)
            (*arr)[i] = NULL;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        if ((*arr)[i] == NULL) {
            (*arr)[i] = (int*)malloc(dim * sizeof(int));

            if (!(*arr)[i]) return;

            break;
        }
        else { //se esiste la posizione allora lo rialloco
            (*arr)[i] = (int*)realloc((*arr)[i], dim * sizeof(int));

            if ((*arr)[i] == NULL) return;
        }
    }
}


void insert_values(int** arr, int dim, int size) {
    if (size > dim) {
        resize(&(arr), size, dim);
    }

    int x;
    int y;

    for (x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            arr[x][y] = x + y;
            printf("%d |", arr[x][y]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}

void print_values(int** arr, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            printf("%d |", arr[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int** x = (int**)malloc(10 * sizeof(*x));

    if (!x) { return 0; }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        x[i] = (int*)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    }

    insert_values(x, 10, 11);
    print_values(x, 11);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        free(x[i]);
    }

    free(x);
}
```

Blockquote